# Can Apache Crunch be used to create Graph like data structure?

Tags: java, hadoop, java-8, mapreduce, apache-crunch

I have two crunch `PCollection` of Edge and Node. I need to convert the structure into a graph that can facilitate smooth traversal through it.
Are there any Apache Crunch methods or classes that I can use to create such a structure?

The data is huge, so I can't load it into memory as a `Collection`.
Also, unfortunately, I can't use any other frameworks specialized for graph processing.